# .get is not a function: When i am getting the value of the input to js controller i am facing the error

Tags: javascript, input, get, onchange, salesforce-lightning

I am using input tag inside the iteration to the table. component.find and get are not working in js controller. Getting the error: This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed:nPrice.get is not a function]
Failing descriptor: {c:SP_TCOSandboxLicense$controller$CalculatePrice}

Component:

```html
    <aura:attribute name="negotiatePrice" type="Integer" />

    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
      <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.userList}" var="con" aura:id="usrLst">
          <tr>
             <th scope="row">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!con.Name}">
                    {!con.Name} 
                </div>
             </th>
             <th scope="row">
               <div aura:id="usrLic" class="slds-truncate" title="{!con.TotalLicenses}">{!con.TotalLicenses}</div>
             </th>
             <th scope="row"> 
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.costList}" var="cst">                                     
                  <aura:if isTrue="{!con.Name == cst.Name}">                                   
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cst.License_Price_Per_Month__c}">{!cst.License_Price_Per_Month__c}</div>
                  </aura:if>
                </aura:iteration>
             </th>
                                        
             <th scope="row" >
               <div class="slds-truncate">
                  <input type="number" aura:id="myAtt" placeholder="Enter Negotiated Price" class="slds-input inputField"  value="{v.negotiatePrice}" onchange="{!c.CalculatePrice}" /> 
                                   
               </div>
             </th>
                                       
           </tr>   
         </aura:iteration>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```js
    CalculatePrice : function(component, event, helper) {  
            
            alert('Calculate');
            var nPrice = component.find("myAtt");
            var negotiatePrice = nPrice.get("v.value");
            alert('negotiatePrice'+negotiatePrice); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use the `event` directly, it will be more efficient:
`event.target.value`

Also if I remember correctly from the time I was writing Aura Component, because you provided `value={!v.negotiatePrice}` you can do `component.get('v.negotiatePrice')` in your controller to get the value.